# Symfony routing with dynamic optional parameters

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I'm new to Symfony framework. Currently I have route in mybundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
fcr_category_head:
  path: head/{slug}/{city}/{page}
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Head:index, slug: "", city: "all", page: 1 }
  requirements: {page: "\d+"}
```

the problem is that `city` option is available when user uses filter to narrow results to selected city, if `city` does not exist, the second parameter should be page.

so route variations can be like this:

```
head/slug/city //default page 1 if city is not a number, if number then it is page
head/slug/city/10 //e.g page 10
head/slug/10 //no city parameter, because it is number, page 10
```

is it possible to make these combinations in routing file or the only way to solve this is tho write my own logic in controller?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for query parameters rather than attributes.  That is far more flexible, what if you wanted to add an additional parameter? Look at most ecom sites, they use query param's in filtering products.

Comment: @Luke Yes, but I have a request, that `city` has to be in this format. I think it is mostly for SEO, other filter parameters will be defined as query parameters as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define two routes for the same action. One with city and one without.

Like this:

```
fcr_category_head:
  path: head/{slug}/{page}
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Head:index, slug: "", city: "all", page: 1 }
  requirements: {page: "\d+"}

fcr_category_head_with_city:
  path: head/{slug}/{city}/{page}
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Head:index, slug: "", city: "all", page: 1 }
  requirements: {page: "\d+", city: "\w+"}
```

First will catch all request like this

```
head/slug/10 
head/slug
```

And second will catch

```
head/slug/city
head/slug/city/10
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that.